# I want to convert [1,223729,2] MLMultiArray data to [473,473,2] grayscale image

Tags: swift, coreml

I want to convert [1,223729,2] MLMultiArray data to [473,473,2] grayscale image on Swift.
Is there any idea?

Comment: What do you mean with grayscale image in this context? What does the input values represent and what does the output values represent?

Comment: Ok.
mlmodel is segmentationmodel.
and I give 473x473 RGB image to mlmodel , and mlmodel give me MLMultiArray type output. And Output is [1,223729,2] shape. 
I want to convert this output to 473x473 grayscale image on Swift.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I mean grayscale image is UI Image or CGImage.
I want to convert MLMultiArray Image to UIImage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reshape the array format.

```
a = np.empty[1,223729,2] # your array
b = a.reshape((473,473,2))
```

Comment: Hi, I mean on Swift.

Comment: Do this in your model and then convert it to Core ML. For grayscale image output you also want to split the (473, 473, 2) tensor into two (473, 473) tensors. Then set the output of the converted model to be an image instead of a multi-array.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Understood.
Do you have any idea about reshape on Swift.